# Запуск скрипта после загрузки страницы (DOM)

Tags: javascript

Есть скрипт, который должен запуститься после загрузки DOM, так как в нём есть обращение к DOM:

```
var element = document.getElementById('element');
element.style.color = 'red';
```

Как мне запустить данный скрипт, чтобы обращение скрипта к DOM сработало?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

### Для тех, кто не знает, почему не работают скрипты с обращением к элементам вида `<script>document.getElementById('element').style.color = 'red';</script>`:

Скрипт пытается взаимодействовать с HTML-элементами на странице, которые находятся ниже по коду, чем сам скрипт. Соответственно, скрипт уже подгрузился, а элемент, с которым нужно будет взаимодействовать, еще нет. По этой причине ничего работать не будет.

Особенность языка Javascript в том, что его код выполняется последовательно, строка за строкой, как они написаны в исходном коде.

### Варианты решения данного вопроса:

1. ***Один из простых способов ― перенести `<script></script>` в body после всех элементов. При таком расположении сначала загрузится DOM, а потом скрипт. Пример:***

   ```
   <body>
      <div>...</div>
      <script>
         // Ваш скрипт
      </script>
   </body>
   ```
2. ***Самый простой способ, который приходит в голову всем новичкам ― указать функцию в `window.onload`. Пример:***

   ```
   window.onload = function() {
      // Ваш скрипт
   };
   ```

Так же можно добавить через `window.addEventListener('load', ...);` или `window.attachEvent('onload', ...);`

Но у этого метода есть недостаток: если на странице сайта куча картинок, которые грузятся пол часа, то скрипт выполнится только после того, как загрузятся все картинки и это может занят много времени.

Ещё одним минусом является то, что нельзя указывать несколько функций таким образом. Т.е. если вы два раза использовали `window.onload` в коде, то вторая функция сотрёт первую. Но, чтобы это исправить, я сочинил интересный костыль:

```
    var windowOnloadAdd = function (event) {
       if ( window.onload ){
          window.onload = window.onload + event;
       } else {
          window.onload = event;
       };
    };

    windowOnloadAdd(function() {
       // Ваш скрипт
    });
```

3. ***Интересный вариант ― что-то между первым и вторым пунктом. Создать особую функцию и вызывать её через скрипт в конце body. Пример:***

   *В JS:*

   ```
   function onload() {
      // Ваш скрипт
   };
   ```

   *В HTML:*

   ```
   <body>
      ...
      <script>
         onload();
      </script>
   </body>
   ```
4. ***Тоже из самых популярных приёмов ― установить для body события `onload`. Пример:***

   *В JS:*

   ```
   function myFunc() {
      // Ваш скрипт
   };
   ```

   *В HTML:*

   ```
   <body onload="myFunc()">...</body>
   ```
5. ***Способ с enStackOveflow ― запуск через функции `document.onreadystatechange` и `document.readyState`. Пример:***

   ```
   document.onreadystatechange = function(){
      if(document.readyState === 'complete'){
         // Ваш скрипт
      }
   }
   ```
6. ***Достаточно новый способ ― запуск через обработчик
   `DOMContentLoaded`. Пример:***

   ```
   document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
      // Ваш скрипт
   }, false);
   ```

   Поддержка этого метода начинается с IE9+
7. ***Ну и подошли варианты с библиотеками. И первая наша библиотека <s>JQuery</s> ScriptJava. Пример:***

   ```
   $$r(function() {
      // Ваш скрипт
   });
   ```

   **[ [Скачать библиотеку](http://scriptjava.net/source/scriptjava/scriptjava.js) ]**
8. ***Вариант, который сработает у всех, кто пользуется JQuery ― использовать JQuery :) . Пример:***

   *Вариант 1:*

   ```
   $(function() {
      // Ваш скрипт
   });
   ```

   *Вариант 2:*

   ```
   $(document).ready(function() {
      // Ваш скрипт
   });
   ```

   **[ [Ссылка на библиотеку](https://jquery.com/) ]**
9. ***Ещё есть вариант с использованием UI YAHOO. К сожалению, чтобы этот метод сработал, нам нужно подключить аж 2 скрипта: `yahoo-min` и `event-min`. Пример:***

   ```
   YAHOO.util.Event.onDOMReady(function(){
      // Ваш скрипт
   });
   ```

   **[ [Скачать "yahoo-min.js"](http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.7.0/build/yahoo/yahoo-min.js) ]** | **[ [Скачать "event-min.js"](http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.7.0/build/event/event-min.js) ]**
10. ***Самый действенный вариант ― [самописная функция со enStackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7053197/5211159). Работает в IE8***:

    var ready = (function(){

    ```
      var readyList,
          DOMContentLoaded,
          class2type = {};
          class2type["[object Boolean]"] = "boolean";
          class2type["[object Number]"] = "number";
          class2type["[object String]"] = "string";
          class2type["[object Function]"] = "function";
          class2type["[object Array]"] = "array";
          class2type["[object Date]"] = "date";
          class2type["[object RegExp]"] = "regexp";
          class2type["[object Object]"] = "object";

       var ReadyObj = {
           // Is the DOM ready to be used? Set to true once it occurs.
           isReady: false,
           // A counter to track how many items to wait for before
           // the ready event fires. See #6781
           readyWait: 1,
           // Hold (or release) the ready event
               holdReady: function( hold ) {
               if ( hold ) {
                   ReadyObj.readyWait++;
               } else {
                   ReadyObj.ready( true );
               }
           },
           // Handle when the DOM is ready
           ready: function( wait ) {
               // Either a released hold or an DOMready/load event and not yet ready
               if ( (wait === true && !--ReadyObj.readyWait) || (wait !== true && !ReadyObj.isReady) ) {
                   // Make sure body exists, at least, in case IE gets a little overzealous (ticket #5443).
                   if ( !document.body ) {
                       return setTimeout( ReadyObj.ready, 1 );
                   }

                   // Remember that the DOM is ready
                   ReadyObj.isReady = true;
                   // If a normal DOM Ready event fired, decrement, and wait if need be
                   if ( wait !== true && --ReadyObj.readyWait > 0 ) {
                       return;
                   }
                   // If there are functions bound, to execute
                   readyList.resolveWith( document, [ ReadyObj ] );

                   // Trigger any bound ready events
                   //if ( ReadyObj.fn.trigger ) {
                   //    ReadyObj( document ).trigger( "ready" ).unbind( "ready" );
                   //}
               }
           },
           bindReady: function() {
               if ( readyList ) {
                   return;
               }
               readyList = ReadyObj._Deferred();

               // Catch cases where $(document).ready() is called after the
               // browser event has already occurred.
               if ( document.readyState === "complete" ) {
                   // Handle it asynchronously to allow scripts the opportunity to delay ready
                   return setTimeout( ReadyObj.ready, 1 );
               }

               // Mozilla, Opera and webkit nightlies currently support this event
               if ( document.addEventListener ) {
                   // Use the handy event callback
                   document.addEventListener( "DOMContentLoaded", DOMContentLoaded, false );
                   // A fallback to window.onload, that will always work
                   window.addEventListener( "load", ReadyObj.ready, false );

               // If IE event model is used
               } else if ( document.attachEvent ) {
                   // ensure firing before onload,
                   // maybe late but safe also for iframes
                   document.attachEvent( "onreadystatechange", DOMContentLoaded );

                   // A fallback to window.onload, that will always work
                   window.attachEvent( "onload", ReadyObj.ready );

                   // If IE and not a frame
                   // continually check to see if the document is ready
                   var toplevel = false;

                   try {
                       toplevel = window.frameElement == null;
                   } catch(e) {}

                   if ( document.documentElement.doScroll && toplevel ) {
                       doScrollCheck();
                   }
               }
           },
           _Deferred: function() {
               var // callbacks list
                   callbacks = [],
                   // stored [ context , args ]
                   fired,
                   // to avoid firing when already doing so
                   firing,
                   // flag to know if the deferred has been cancelled
                   cancelled,
                   // the deferred itself
                   deferred  = {

                       // done( f1, f2, ...)
                       done: function() {
                           if ( !cancelled ) {
                               var args = arguments,
                                   i,
                                   length,
                                   elem,
                                   type,
                                   _fired;
                               if ( fired ) {
                                   _fired = fired;
                                   fired = 0;
                               }
                               for ( i = 0, length = args.length; i < length; i++ ) {
                                   elem = args[ i ];
                                   type = ReadyObj.type( elem );
                                   if ( type === "array" ) {
                                       deferred.done.apply( deferred, elem );
                                   } else if ( type === "function" ) {
                                       callbacks.push( elem );
                                   }
                               }
                               if ( _fired ) {
                                   deferred.resolveWith( _fired[ 0 ], _fired[ 1 ] );
                               }
                           }
                           return this;
                       },

                   // resolve with given context and args
                   resolveWith: function( context, args ) {
                       if ( !cancelled && !fired && !firing ) {
                           // make sure args are available (#8421)
                           args = args || [];
                           firing = 1;
                           try {
                               while( callbacks[ 0 ] ) {
                                   callbacks.shift().apply( context, args );//shifts a callback, and applies it to document
                               }
                           }
                           finally {
                               fired = [ context, args ];
                               firing = 0;
                           }
                       }
                       return this;
                   },

                   // resolve with this as context and given arguments
                   resolve: function() {
                       deferred.resolveWith( this, arguments );
                       return this;
                   },

                   // Has this deferred been resolved?
                   isResolved: function() {
                       return !!( firing || fired );
                   },

                   // Cancel
                   cancel: function() {
                       cancelled = 1;
                       callbacks = [];
                       return this;
                   }
               };

           return deferred;
       },
       type: function( obj ) {
           return obj == null ?
               String( obj ) :
               class2type[ Object.prototype.toString.call(obj) ] || "object";
       }
    ```

    }
    // The DOM ready check for Internet Explorer
    function doScrollCheck() {
    if ( ReadyObj.isReady ) {
    return;
    }

    ```
       try {
           // If IE is used, use the trick by Diego Perini
           // http://javascript.nwbox.com/IEContentLoaded/
           document.documentElement.doScroll("left");
       } catch(e) {
           setTimeout( doScrollCheck, 1 );
           return;
       }

       // and execute any waiting functions
       ReadyObj.ready();
    ```

    }
    // Cleanup functions for the document ready method
    if ( document.addEventListener ) {
    DOMContentLoaded = function() {
    document.removeEventListener( "DOMContentLoaded", DOMContentLoaded, false );
    ReadyObj.ready();
    };

    } else if ( document.attachEvent ) {
    DOMContentLoaded = function() {
    // Make sure body exists, at least, in case IE gets a little overzealous (ticket #5443).
    if ( document.readyState === "complete" ) {
    document.detachEvent( "onreadystatechange", DOMContentLoaded );
    ReadyObj.ready();
    }
    };
    }
    function ready( fn ) {
    // Attach the listeners
    ReadyObj.bindReady();

    ```
       var type = ReadyObj.type( fn );

          // Add the callback
          readyList.done( fn );//readyList is result of _Deferred()
      }
      return ready;
      })();
    ```

```
 

    ready(function() {
       // Ваш скрипт
    });
```

11. ***И наконец самый странный и не всегда рабочий вариант ― использовать setTimeout. Пример:***

    setTimout(function() {
    // Ваш скрипт
    }, 3000);

Это все варианты, которые я встречал, но возможно не единственный, так как другие программисты могли придумать свои функции для решения данной задачи.

Какой вариант использовать, решать вам :)

Comment: setTimeout не обязан работать - страница может быть всё ещё загружаться в тот момент, когда он сработает.

Comment: @Qwertiy, добавил это. Ну это я на сайте одном увидел, что некоторые так решать решили :)

Answer (score 5):

Еще забыли про атрибут defer. [htmlbook](http://htmlbook.ru/html/script/defer)

```
<script defer>
  // код
</script>
```

Comment: лучше написать это в комментарий к ответу

Comment: Пожалуйста, при выборе источника для ссылки, избегайте сайтов напичканых рекламой,

Comment: На момент ответа, таких технологий ещё не было 