# Почему не срабатывает querySelectorAll?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, queryselectorall

Ребят подскажите почему может не срабатывать такой пример.

```js
mass = ["2610028", "1596552"];
if (!mass) {
  console.log('Nastroek net');
} else {
  var index;
  for (index = 0; index < mass.length; ++index) {
    console.log(mass[index]); //выводит верные числа
    var urlx = document.querySelectorAll('a[href$="' + mass[index] + '"]'); //
    console.log(urlx); // NodeList []
    console.log(urlx.length); //0
    for (var i = 0; i < urlx.length; i++) {
      console.log(urlx[0]); //undefined
      var tr_str = urlx[i].parentElement.parentElement;
      var tb2_td = tr_str.querySelector('td:nth-child(2n)');
      var chislo = tb2_td.innerHTML;
      tr_str.querySelector('input[name="table_checkbox_' + chislo + '"]').checked = true;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<table border='1'>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="1" align="center">
        <div>
          <label for="form-table-table_checkbox_1208837">
            <input type="checkbox" name="table_checkbox_1208837" id="form-table-table_checkbox_1208837">
        </label>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>1208831</td>
      <td data-sum="1">
        <a href="_order?id=2343027">2343027</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="1" align="center">
        <div>
          <label for="form-table-table_checkbox_1200037">
            <input type="checkbox" name="table_checkbox_1200037" id="form-table-table_checkbox_1200037">
        </label>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>1200031</td>
      <td data-sum="1">
        <a href="_order?id=2610027">2610027</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="1" align="center">
        <div>
          <label for="form-table-table_checkbox_1200032">
            <input type="checkbox" name="table_checkbox_1200032" id="form-table-table_checkbox_1200032">
        </label>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>1200032</td>
      <td data-sum="1">
        <a href="_order?id=2610028">2610028</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="1" align="center">
        <div>
          <label for="form-table-table_checkbox_1200033">
            <input type="checkbox" name="table_checkbox_1200033" id="form-table-table_checkbox_1200033">
        </label>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>1200033</td>
      <td data-sum="0">
        <a href="_order?id=2610028">2610028</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="1" align="center">
        <div>
          <label for="form-table-table_checkbox_1200034">
            <input type="checkbox" name="table_checkbox_1200034" id="form-table-table_checkbox_1200034">
         </label>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>1200034</td>
      <td data-sum="0">
        <a href="_order?id=2610028">2610028</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

То есть, здесь и на всяких там https://jsfiddle.net/fe1o7syb/ все срабатывает как надо. Но у меня срабатывает до вот этого момента:

```
var urlx = document.querySelectorAll('a[href$="'+mass[index]+'"]');
```

а дальше нет. Пробовал даже явно указывать адрес ссылки: `var urlx = document.querySelectorAll('a[href="_order?id='+mass[index]+'"]');`

Все равно не работает. С чем это может быть связано?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваш код выполняется до того, как созданы DOM-элементы, которые Вы ищете.

Comment: Тогда можно ли как то понять, что весь dom уже построен?  Не выполнять же мне скрипт по таймеру?

Comment: @Kamupo Заверните код в `window.addEventListener("load", function() { ... });`

Comment: окей, попробую.

Comment: Добавлю еще. Полезно так же ознакомиться с этой темой. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/688566/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B-dom